# How to build fortran code in Eclipse 12s IDE (Scientific) on macOS Big Sur

Tags: eclipse, fortran, gfortran

I downloaded and installed Scientific Eclipse (2020 -12s) on my macBook but my "Hello, World!" code won't build.  I suspect that the error below means that my GNU FORTRAN (gfortran) was not found, but the PATH variable has /usr/local/bin in it.  Dr. Google has not found any answers that address the problem.  I have not been able to find anyplace in the Eclipse files to specifically add the path.  Bringing up 'sh' in terminal and entering 'gfortran' results in the expected error of 'no files'.

```
% which gfortran
/usr/local/bin/gfortran
```

Code:

```
program Hello
    implicit none
    print *, 'Hello, World!'
end program Hello
```

Eclipse build error:

```
11:55:48 **** Build of configuration Debug for project Learn ****
make all 
Building file: ../Hello.f90
Invoking: GNU Fortran Compiler
gfortran -funderscoring -O0 -g -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -o "Hello.o" "../Hello.f90"
/bin/sh: gfortran: command not found
make: *** [Hello.o] Error 127
"make all" terminated with exit code 2. Build might be incomplete.
```

Comment: Eclipse 2020-12 is outdated ... since a couple of hours. Does the issue still exist in Eclipse 2021-03?

Comment: @howlger I updated, thanks, but no joy - still doesn't find fortran.